# const Router = require ('Router'), showing error in nodemon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, nodemon

```
E:\express\inotebook\backend\routes\notes.js:2
var router = express.Router();
^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\express\inotebook\backend\index.js:10:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
[nodemon] starting `node index.jss index.js`
E:\express\inotebook\backend\routes\notes.js:2
var router = express.Router();
^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\express\inotebook\backend\index.js:10:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.jss index.js`
E:\express\inotebook\backend\routes\notes.js:2
const Router = require ('Router'),
^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\express\inotebook\backend\index.js:10:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Can you post the whole file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.